# Git how to diff branch1/dir/* against branch2/*?

Tags: git

How can I make this git diff work? Using the docs I can only find out how to diff 2 entire branches, or dirs/files in the branch that have the same root. Though, I need to diff branch1/dir/* against branch2/*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
git diff branch1:dir/ branch2:
```

This should give the desired output.